# Как скопировать одно свойство инфоблока и подставить в другое свойство этого же инфоблока. Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем привет. Допустим, есть кастомное свойство инфоблока PROPERTY_1, в нем хранится некое значение n.
Как его можно скопировать в другое свойство этого же инфоблока, которое называется, скажем, PROPERTY_2
Ручками сделать всегда можно, конечно, но что, если товаров будет очень много? Заранее спасибо)

Пытался вот так:

```
if (!CModule::IncludeModule("iblock"))
die('Модуль "Инфоблоки" не найден!');

$rsElements = CIBlockElement::GetList(array("NAME" => "ASC"), array("IBLOCK_ID" => 68));

$rsElement = new CIBlockElement;

$iHeight = 800;
$iWidth = 1000;

while ($arElement = $rsElements->Fetch()) {
    if ($arElement["REAL_PICTURE"] != "") {
        $arPreview = CFile::ResizeImageGet($arElement["REAL_PICTURE"], array('width' => $iWidth, 'height' => $iHeight), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_PROPORTIONAL, false);
        $arLoadProductArray = Array(
            //"REAL_PICTURE"  => CFile::MakeFileArray(CFile::GetPath($arElement["REAL_PICTURE"])),
            "DETAIL_PICTURE" => CFile::MakeFileArray($arPreview["src"]),
        );
        
        if ($rsElement->Update($arElement["ID"], $arLoadProductArray)) {
            echo "Элемент {$arElement["ID"]} обновлён.<br />\n";
        }
    } elseif ($arElement["DETAIL_PICTURE"] != "") {
        $arOld = CFile::GetFileArray($arElement["DETAIL_PICTURE"]);

        if (($arOld["WIDTH"] > $iWidth) || ($arOld["HEIGHT"] > $iHeight)) {
            $arLoadProductArray = Array(
                "REAL_PICTURE"  => CFile::MakeFileArray($arOld["SRC"]),
            );
            if ($rsElement->Update($arElement["ID"], $arLoadProductArray)) {
                $arNew = CFile::ResizeImageGet($arElement["DETAIL_PICTURE"], array("width" => $iWidth, "height" => $iHeight), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_PROPORTIONAL, false);
                $arLoadProductArray = Array(
                    "DETAIL_PICTURE" => CFile::MakeFileArray($arNew["src"]),
                );
                if ($rsElement->Update($arElement["ID"], $arLoadProductArray)) {
                    echo "Элемент {$arElement["ID"]} обновлён.<br />\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Не вышло(

Comment: пользуйте для этого массивы

Comment: кодом можно, делаете php скрипт, используете bitrix api. Подключаете ядро битрикса, берёте данные какие нужно копировать (откуда нужно брать их), записываете туда куда надо вставить (внимательно читайте документацию некоторые методы при обновление могут затереть все непереданные свойства).

Comment: В том то и дело, что я читал, пробовал, писал скрипт, а он не сработал =-(

Comment: что значит не сработал? Если скрипт остановился на конкретной ошибке то исправьте её, проверьте что возвращают методы api обновляют данные или нет.  Используйте дебаг можно просто выводить что то echo  (в if и до них) что бы понять попадает ли в условие ваш случай (у вас много if -ов всяких). Обратите внимание что CIBlockElement метод Update затрёт все свойства, у обновляемого элемента, если их не передать в метод. (Может вам нужен метод SetPropertyValuesEx, почитайте про него)